# getting error: bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, eclipse

Need to install st-linkv2 in eclipse for stm32f4 programming.

automake, dh-autoreconf, libusb-1.0-0-dev are required for st-linkv2.

Terminal looks like this:

```
abin@abin-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~/ARMToolchains/stlink-master$ ls -a
.               debian        LICENSE                 .travis.sh
..              doc           Makefile                .travis.yml
.appveyor.yml   etc           README.md               usr
build           flashloaders  scripts                 .version
ChangeLog.md    .github       src
cmake           .gitignore    stlinkv1_macosx_driver
CMakeLists.txt  include       tests
$ ./autogen.sh
bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
$ whereis automake
automake: /usr/share/man/man1/automake.1.gz
$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
$ sudo apt-get install automake
[sudo] password for abin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
automake is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
$ whereis autoconf
autoconf: /usr/bin/autoconf /usr/share/autoconf /usr/share/man/man1/autoconf.1.gz
$ whereis libusb-1.0-0-dev
libusb-1: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
```

I have downloaded the source from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/texane/stlink).

I've been blindly following [this You Tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKX12hJApZM) which shows how to use Eclipse in Linux for STMboard programming and dumping the code into the board. The maker of the video performs the operation I'm trying to do at 8:37.

OS is Ubuntu 15.04, 32-bit.

I would like to know how to compile this. I also want to understand why we use methods like `./autogen.sh` and other commands.

Comment: Why do you think you should be running `./autogen.sh`? based on the directory contents in your screenshot, the software's build system appears to be  `cmake` rather than GNU autotools.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Instead, copy and paste the text into your question, select the text, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex done !

Comment: @steeldriver do not know why but would want to know the reasons.

Comment: @Zanna edited and details are added, please check!

Comment: According to the stlink [compiling manual](https://github.com/texane/stlink/blob/master/doc/compiling.md) it should be sufficient to run `make release` from the top-level directory - which should create a `build` directory and run the necessary `cmake` and `make` commands to configure and build the installation.

Comment: @steeldriver   i tried the command please check: `abin@abin-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~/ARMToolchains/stlink-master$ make release
[RELEASE]
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'release' failed
make: *** [release] Error 2
abin@abin-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~/ARMToolchains/stlink-master$ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using

```
./name-of-file
```

runs an executable in the current working directory. If you cannot see `name-of-file` with `ls -a` it will fail with the error you saw, and if it does not have execute permission for the user running the command, it will fail with `permission denied` (if there are no x bits set at all, and you try running it with `sudo`, the fail message will be `command not found`)

The program you are trying to compile uses the `cmake` method to set up the build environment, and there is evidently no `autogen.sh` (or `configure`) script to run.

I just successfully built [this release](https://github.com/texane/stlink/archive/1.3.1.tar.gz) from the GitHub page you linked to. It was straightforward, and I didn't encounter any problems.

First you need to install all the dependencies for the build. I'm not sure if all this is actually required, but you mentioned needing some of it anyway...

```
sudo apt install build-essential automake dh-autoreconf libusb-1.0-0-dev cmake g++
```

make a directory at the location shown in your screenshot (open a terminal and `cd /ARMToolchains/stlink-master` if necessary... why aren't you building in your home directory? I recommend moving the whole directory to `$USER`, but anyway...) the basic method is

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

When that exits successfully, you can run

```
make
```

If that exists successfully, you may run

```
sudo make install
```

To move the binaries to the correct locations. If not, you can run them from the current directory. If you can't get the version you've already downloaded to build (this happens quite often when cloning the master as it might be in the process of getting tweaked), then download one of the releases (like the one I linked above) and try again.

Comment: That's a clean answer, amazing. Anyhow in process i got this `/home/abin/ARMToolchains/stlink-master# apt install build-essential automake dh-autoreconf libusb-1.0-0-dev cmake g++
The following extra packages will be installed:
 cmake-data
Suggested packages:
  codeblocks eclipse ninja-build
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cmake cmake-data
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,324 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] `

Comment: All works fine, but for make install `abin@abin-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~/ARMToolchains/stlink-master$ pwd
/home/abin/ARMToolchains/stlink-master
abin@abin-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:~/ARMToolchains/stlink-master$ sudo make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.`

Comment: Hmm @abinjacob maybe you can run the executables from where they are... not at my box, so not sure

Comment: don't leave like that , please answer

Comment: @abinjacob I can't test it or look into it because I'm not at my machine now, I'm at work. I will take a look later :S

Comment: gives hope , peace gn :)

Comment: @abinjacob it works for me like so --> http://paste.ubuntu.com/24083002/ see the install_manifest.txt inside the directory for where the files should go. I can only suggest you try the **release version** (linked in my answer) download it to your `~/Downloads` directory and build from there. If that doesn't work, I have no idea, because I can't reproduce your problem :( Sorry!

Comment: @abinjacob however, when you try it like this, you can copy and paste the output from all commands [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and put the link to your paste here and I can take a look

Comment: What is the "release version" mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I installed a release from GitHub rather than cloning the master [click here to download it](https://github.com/texane/stlink/archive/1.3.1.tar.gz) @abinjacob

Comment: make install did run, in build folder. It did work!!                                                      it was not running before because i used "cmake" instead of           "cmake .." .What is the significance of  ".."?

Comment: it signifies the parent directory, where the CMakeFiles are located. Glad you got it working! @abinjacob